# FileStream.Read() Throws ArgumentException

Tags: c#, aes, filestream

I would like to make some secure container for my application, and here's the map :

[image]

I finished opening/saving code now, and tested it, however, `ArgumentException` was thrown.

The code will run like this.

1. Create `byte[]` type variable for containing not crypted user data.
2. `FileStream` Writes Magic Number to first 5 bytes.
3. `RijndaelManaged` accepts key, and generates Initialization Vector.
4. `FileStream` Writes Initialization Vector to next 16 bytes. **<- Exception thrown!**
5. `CryptoStream` transform the variable from 1.
6. `FileStream` Writes the crypted data from 22th bytes.

Debugging, and I found the reason that `FileStream.Read()` has been thrown the Exception. and the message is:

**Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.**

I tried to set the length of stream as (user data) + 21. but it doesn't work. I attach entire code for saving file, and I hope this problem will be solved.

Thank you!

```
    private bool SaveFile(string FilePath, bool IsCrypt) 
    {
        byte[] Data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(WorkspaceList[CurrentIndex]._textbox.Text);

        using (var Stream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {

            if (IsCrypt)
            {
                Stream.SetLength(Data.Length + 21); // Tried when I got Exception
                Stream.Write(MagicNumber, 0, 5); //Magic Number

                using (var CryptoHandler = new RijndaelManaged()) // AES256 Encryption
                {
                    CryptoHandler.BlockSize = 128;
                    CryptoHandler.KeySize = 256;
                    CryptoHandler.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                    CryptoHandler.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                    var tempKey = WorkspaceList[CurrentIndex]._cryptkey;

                    if(tempKey.Length < 32)
                    {
                        tempKey.PadRight(32);
                    }
                    else if (tempKey.Length > 32)
                    {
                        tempKey.Remove(33);
                    }

                    CryptoHandler.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(WorkspaceList[CurrentIndex]._cryptkey.PadRight(32));
                    CryptoHandler.GenerateIV();

                    Stream.Write(CryptoHandler.IV, 5, 16); //IV Insertion *** ArgumentException ***
                    var CryptoInstance = CryptoHandler.CreateEncryptor(CryptoHandler.Key, CryptoHandler.IV);

                    using (var MemoryHandler = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var Crypto = new CryptoStream(MemoryHandler, CryptoInstance, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            byte[] _Buffer = Data;
                            Crypto.Read(Data, 0, Data.Length);
                            _Buffer = MemoryHandler.ToArray();

                            Stream.Write(_Buffer, 21, _Buffer.Length); // Insert Crypted Data
                            Stream.Close();

                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Stream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
                Stream.Close();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 5 makes no sense, it is not the offset in the file.  Pass 0 instead so you'll write all of the bytes in the IV.  Favor CryptoHandler.IV.Length instead of 16.  It is wrong again at 21.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Stream.Write(CryptoHandler.IV, 5, 16); //IV Insertion`

With `Stream.Write(CryptoHandler.IV, 0, CryptoHandler.IV.Length); //IV Insertion`

array = CryptoHandler.IV (the data you want to write)

offset  = 0 (you write from the first byte of array)

count = CryptoHandler.IV.Length (you write all bytes from CryptoHandler.IV)

Note that offset is intrinsic to array, not to the Stream. After a successful Write operation, the stream cursor waits at the last written position. I suppose you specified an offset of 5 to take into account the MagicNumber?
You would have add the same problem with `Stream.Write(_Buffer, 21, _Buffer.Length);`